# Concatenating column values of identical rows (except for this column) of two different data tables

Tags: r, addition, multiple-tables

I have two data tables of genes aggHuman and aggRat

```
> aggHuman
   Human     Rat RNAtype
1   ASAP2   Asap2      Hy
2    BBS1    Bbs1      Hn
3    BBS2    Bbs2      Hn
4 SPATA22 Spata22      Hn
```

and

```
  > aggRat
    Human     Rat RNAtype
1   ASAP2   Asap2      Rn
2    BBS1    Bbs1      Ry
3    BBS2    Bbs2      Rn
4 SPATA22 Spata22      Rn
```

Now, I want to stitch the values in column RNAtype of these two tables. For example, in aggHuman for ASAP2 we have Hy, whereas in aggRat, we have Rn. Now, I want to make another similar table of the following form by stitching HyRn.

```
        Human     Rat RNAtype
    1   ASAP2   Asap2      HyRn
```

But the initial two tables can have genes in different order. So, what I need to do is find the row corresponding to ASAP2 in aggHuman and "find" the same gene row in aggRat and then do the stitch thing.

Could anyone help me on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Step 1: Load data.table library (you may need to install this):

```
library(data.table)
```

Step 2: Convert your data.frame to data.table, and set appropriate keys:

```
setDT(aggHuman)
setkey(aggHuman,Human,Rat)
setDT(aggRat)
setkey(aggRat,Human,Rat)
```

Step 3: Join the two data tables, and perform desired combination:

```
aggHumanRat <- aggHuman[aggRat]
aggHumanRat[,RNAtype := paste(RNAtype,RNAtype.1,sep="")][,RNAtype.1:=NULL]
aggHumanRat
```

Hope this helps!!